# Which cards feature direct manipulation of counter types on permanents?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there any magic cards that allow for direct manipulation of arbitrary counter types? Eg, "Add a counter of any kind to target permanent"?

At this point (2014) I would be surprised if something along these lines didn't exist in some form or another, its ridiculously powerful abuse potential notwithstanding.

*Edit: My apologies for such an easily query-able answer. I was not aware of the existence o such comprehensive databases and easily-searchable databases like magiccards.info before posting these questions. I will surely do more research from now on. Thank you!*

Answer (score 4):

[Clockspinning](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clockspinning), [Gilder Bairn](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gilder%20Bairn) and [Vorel of the Hull Clade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vorel%20of%20the%20Hull%20Clade) allow you to add another counter of a kind that already exists on a permanent, and so does the [Proliferate](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3Aproliferate) keyword.

And then there's [Doubling Season](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Doubling%20Season) which doubles the number of counters placed on permanents.

Comment: If you're mentioning proliferate, you should probably also mention [Gilder Bairn](http://magiccards.info/eve/en/152.html) and [Vorel of the Hull Clade](http://magiccards.info/dgm/en/115.html).

Comment: @jwodder, Added to the list.

Comment: Since you mentioned Doubling Season, it's fun to note that when a planeswalker comes into play Doubling Season doubles the number of loyalty counters initially placed on it. Ex: Play Nicol Bolas, Planeswalker, he normally comes in with 5 counters, Doubling Season makes him come in with 10, boom ult him, the first turn hes out.

Comment: It is only +1/+1 but Hardened Scales feels like it belongs since it effects all creatures you control.